# How can I search in Firebase using two child values?

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the nodes from a Firebase realtime database where the search result is matched with the child value. For example, consider my following Firebase structure:

```
    -Users
        -uid
            -uname:abc
            -usurname:xyz
        -uid
            -uname:abc
            -usurname:pqr
        -uid
            -uname:hij
            -usurname:xyz
```

My search key is `abc xyz`. I want to get results from both -uname and -usurname to show the user as matched result from Firebase.

**My code:**

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("uname").startAt(getInput).orderByChild("usurname").startAt(getInput);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.e("app","found: "+snapshot.getValue());
            }
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**The error:**

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!
            at com.google.firebase.database.Query.validateNoOrderByCall(Query.java:134)
            at com.google.firebase.database.Query.orderByChild(Query.java:609)
```

How can I write a Query for that in Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. I am assuming that you've split your search keys into two strings i.e. searchKey1 & searchKey2 like below.

```
    String searchKey="abc xyz";
    String[] str=searchKey.split(" ");
    String searchKey1=str[0];
    String searchKey2=str[1];

    // OR YOU CAN SPLIT HOWEVER YOU WANT //
    

databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(dataSnapshot1.child("uname").exists()&&dataSnapshot1.child("usurname").exists()) {
                    if(dataSnapshot1.child("uname").getValue().toString().equals(searchKey1)&&dataSnapshot1.child("usurname").getValue().toString().equals(searchKey2)) {
                        //Do What You Want To Do.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thats exact search. Does it returns multiple matched results?

Comment: Yes, it will return multiple searches i.e. if uname and usurname matches multiple times in the list, then the if condition will run multiple times. If you add break at the last line in the if block, then it will run for the first time only.

Comment: Good. How can i limit to first 50 results then while scrolling get another next 50 results?

Comment: In the if block, store all the DataSnaphots in an ArrayList and then, fetch 50 at a time and then store the index and then, on scrolling increment it by 50 each time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another attribute called `uname_usuername`, that will contain the two values, then you can do:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = reference.child("users").orderByChild("uname_usuername").equalTo("abc_xyz");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // do something with the data
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```